# Increase max key size LMDB key value database in python?

Tags: python, lmdb

I have an application where I need to use long keys to store values in a key value store database. If I try to store a value using a long key (greater than 511 bytes) in lmdb, using the python API, I receive the following error:

```
lmdb.BadValsizeError: mdb_put: MDB_BAD_VALSIZE: Unsupported size of key/DB name/data, or wrong DUPFIXED size
```

See the example code:

```
>>> short_key = 'short_key'
>>> long_key = 'long_key' * 100
>>> print(f'short_key ({len(short_key.encode())} bytes), long_key ({len(long_key.encode())} bytes)')
short_key (9 bytes), long_key (800 bytes)
```

Initialise lmdb environment and check max key size:

```
>>> import lmdb
>>> env = lmdb.open('db_folder')
>>> print(f'Max key bytes = {env.max_key_size()}')
Max key bytes = 511
```

Insert value using short key works fine:

```
>>> with env.begin(write=True) as txn:
...     txn.put(short_key.encode(), '1'.encode())
...
True
```

However with long key the following error is raised:

```
>>> with env.begin(write=True) as txn:
...     txn.put(long_key.encode(), '2'.encode())
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
lmdb.BadValsizeError: mdb_put: MDB_BAD_VALSIZE: Unsupported size of key/DB name/data, or wrong DUPFIXED size
```

The documentation [here](https://lmdb.readthedocs.io/en/release/) says :

> By default record keys are limited to 511 bytes in length, however this can be adjusted by rebuilding the library. The compile-time key length can be queried via Environment.max_key_size().

I am not sure how to follow these instructions? Any advice on how to get around this issue much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can recompile lmdb (found here: https://github.com/LMDB/lmdb/tree/mdb.master/libraries/liblmdb) with a compile-time option to set the maximum key size.

```
make -j $NUM_JOBS XCFLAGS=-DMDB_MAXKEYSIZE=0
```

Note that using 0 will use the so-called computed max, which is a bit less than half of the page size of your OS (see http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/group__internal.html#gac929399f5d93cef85f874b9e9b1d09e0). Other values are also accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this question. And I didn't find the solution to increase the key size. Rebuilding LMDB is too hard for me.
I compressed the long key by SVD. In fact the long key will slow down query.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33890321)